# What is the best way to read number from console using scanner?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a function to validate the user's input. It only returns when the user inputs a double number.

```
private static double getDouble(String name) {
    double res = 0;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please input " + name + ":");
        if (s.hasNextDouble()) {
            res = s.nextDouble();
            break;
        }
        else s.nextLine();
    }
    s.close();
    return res;
}
```

However, it only works first time. If I call the function second time right after the first time, the `nextLine()` will throw an exception.

```
double length = 0, width = 0;
length = getDouble("length of picture");
width = getDouble("width of picture");
```

Please see the [image: Output Screenshot]

Could someone tell me what the mistake I have made here? And how to fix/avoid it?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.util.NoSuchElementException - Scanner reading user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042008/java-util-nosuchelementexception-scanner-reading-user-input)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made another way for getting user input. Just refer to the code and code comments for details.

```
private static double getDouble(String name) {
    double res = 0;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Please input " + name + ":");
            res = Double.parseDouble(s.nextLine()); // Just get the user input as a string then try to convert it into a double
            break; // if there is no error in the string to double conversion it means that the input is valid, thus break the loop
        } catch (Exception e) { // catch possible errors in case the input is invalid
            System.out.println("Your input is invalid!"); // print desired error message then the loop will execute again getting another user input
        }
    }
    s.close();
    return res;
}
```

**EDIT**
It is because you have close the scanner instance after the method. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622556/scanner-method-opened-and-closed-twice) why that won't work. You could also refer to that for alternatives.

If you want to use `hasNextDouble` then you could either pass the scanner as a parameter to your `getDouble` method or declare the scanner as a class variable. Both will result to only declaring and closing 1 Scanner.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        double tmp = getDouble(s, "Tmp");
        double tmp2 = getDouble(s, "Tmp");
        s.close();
    }

    private static double getDouble(Scanner s, String name) {
        double res = 0;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Please input " + name + ":");
            if (s.hasNextDouble()) {
                res = s.nextDouble();
                break;
            } else
                s.nextLine();
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain why I got the error? Is there a way to use nextDouble() to get the input?

Comment: @user5301398 `nextDouble` doesn't consume the new line character that's in the remaining buffer

Comment: @user5301398 I have edited my answer, kindly refer to it

Comment: @MadProgrammer Is there a solution for this? I tried to add a `nextLine()` after `nextDouble()`, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @user5301398 Personally, I use `nextLine` and then parse the result as this solves all this kind of issues

Comment: The second solution is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

When you close the Scanner object (`s.close();`)  for **System.in** you can't use scanner again until you restart your application. It's best to leave the Scanner object open until you are absolutely sure you won't need it again.

Personally, I really don't like purposely relying on exceptions to take care of invalid situation but in this case it's extremely suited for it:

```
private static double getDouble(String name) {
    double res = 0.0d;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (res == 0.0d) {
        System.out.print("Please input " + name + ": --> ");
        try {
            res = s.nextDouble(); 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) { 
            // If input is invalid
            System.out.println("Your input is invalid! Numerical Values Only!"); 
            /* Clear the scanner buffer otherwise the response 
               above will continue to display over and over 
               again.            */
            s.nextLine();   
            res = 0.0d;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

You can also do this without using an exception trap:

```
private static double getDouble(String name) {
    String res = "";
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (res.equals("")) {
        System.out.print("Please input " + name + ": ");
        res = s.nextLine();
        /* If the User supplies anything that is NOT a string 
           representation of a signed or unsigned integer or 
           double type numerical value. A regular Expression is 
           used here with the String#matches() method.       */
        if (!res.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
            // Input is invalid...
            System.out.println("Your input is invalid (" + res + ")! Only Integer or Double Type Numerical Values Are Allowed!");
            res = "";
        }
    }
    return Double.parseDouble(res);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution is what i'm looking for, but I have taken Mark's.